# How can I prevent gdal_translate from rounding coordinates when clipping?

Tags: raster, clip, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I want to clip a raster (a VRT of several Ascii files) to a set of coordinates. Ideally I'd like to use `gdal_translate` to do this, but I only get an accurate result when using `gdalwarp`. `gdal_translate` seems to round the clipping coordinates given in `-projwin`.

Here's a zoomed-in view of the corner of the clipped rasters when loaded into QGIS:

[image]

The corner of the clipped output should align with the diagonal line. The black rectangle (output of `gdal_translate`) is misaligned, the red rectangle (output of `gdalwarp`) is correct.

The `gdal_translate` command I used is:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -projwin 429101.22 84985.077 429701.22 84785.077 83fb4946-fcdf-4536-b859-36b999efde7d_DTM.vrt one.vrt
```

QGIS shows that the extents of the clipped output are:

```
429100.0000000000000000,84786.0000000000000000 :
429700.0000000000000000,84986.0000000000000000
```

It looks as though `gdal_translate` has rounded or altered these.

The `gdalwarp` command I used is:

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -cutline box.shp -crop_to_cutline -overwrite -of VRT 83fb4946-fcdf-4536-b859-36b999efde7d_DTM.vrt two.vrt
```

Where box.shp contains a rectangle with the same coordinates as those used in the `gdal_translate` command. QGIS shows that the extents of this clipped output are:

```
429101.2199999999720603,84785.0770000000047730 :
429701.2199999999720603,84985.0770000000047730
```

Which is much closer to the correct coordinates.

Is there a way to stop this rounding taking place when using `gdal_translate`?

**Edit:** I'm using GDAL 1.10.1

**Edit:** Here's the output of `gdalinfo` on a similar VRT:

```
Driver: VRT/Virtual Raster
Files: dd84ed63-b0c2-486f-a61c-8dea3d780552_DTM.vrt
   /Users/.../dd84ed63-b0c2-486f-a61c-8dea3d780552/sz2883_DTM_2m.asc
   /Users/.../dd84ed63-b0c2-486f-a61c-8dea3d780552/sz2884_DTM_2m.asc
   /Users/.../dd84ed63-b0c2-486f-a61c-8dea3d780552/sz2885_DTM_2m.asc
   /Users/.../dd84ed63-b0c2-486f-a61c-8dea3d780552/sz2983_DTM_2m.asc
   /Users/.../dd84ed63-b0c2-486f-a61c-8dea3d780552/sz2984_DTM_2m.asc
   /Users/.../dd84ed63-b0c2-486f-a61c-8dea3d780552/sz2985_DTM_2m.asc
Size is 1000, 1500
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (428000.000000000000000,86000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (2.000000000000000,-2.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  428000.000,   86000.000) 
Lower Left  (  428000.000,   83000.000) 
Upper Right (  430000.000,   86000.000) 
Lower Right (  430000.000,   83000.000) 
Center      (  429000.000,   84500.000) 
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Comment: You can't align to pixel edges that your grid does not have, gdal has to snap to whole pixels and presumably your projwin does not share that alignment. We could tell if you gave the output of gdalinfo on your input .vrt, or if you showed the individual pixels in QGIS above.  What you are asking for implies resampling to a new grid, which is what gdalwarp does.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks. I thought gdal_translate also resampled the pixels. I've added the output of gdalinfo on a similar .VRT in case you want to leave an answer.